# Python 2.7 exception handling

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I'm using python 2.7, I've build a custom exception class, and when i'm catching this exception the program doesn't stop.

Here is a snippet from my code:

```
try:
    result = OsUtils.is_os_name_valid(allowedSystems)
    print "This is the result: {0}".format(result)
    if result is False:
        raise ErrorUnsupportedOsSystemException(OsUtils.get_os_type())
except ErrorUnsupportedOsSystemException as e:
    print "({0}) {1}, ".format(e.os_type, e.message)
except IOError as e:
    print "I/O error ({0}) : {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    raise
print "Test"
```

This is the exception class:

```
class ErrorUnsupportedOsSystemException(Exception):
    message = "Error: unsupported system!!"

    def __init__(self, os_type):
        self.os_type = os_type

    pass
```

Here is the output that i'm getting:

```
This is the result: False
(posix) Error: unsupported system!!, 
Test
```

The "Test" shouldn't been printed.

Comment: why shouldn't it?  after the except block executes, your program will continue as normal.

Comment: The `print` is after the `except` block. Exceptions don't stop the program when they are catched.

Comment: I'm new in python, how can i write in a way which will exit from the program once an exception is caught?

Comment: `sys.exit(0)` or `raise` like in your last `except` block

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.  Make it work with your code.

```
import sys

try:
    things...
except ErrorThatJustShouldBeLogged as e:
    log an error or something
except ErrorThatShouldExitProgram as e:
    sys.exit(0)
```